# Adding second child to dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

Im experiencing an issue adding a second child to the drop-down-menu.
here is my html code:

```
<ul class="sidenav sidenav-fixed" id="nav-mobile">
  <li>
    <a onclick="load('file-name')"><i class="material- 
     icons">home</i>TEXT
    </a>
  </li>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <li><a onclick="load('file-name')"><i class="material- 
   icons">apps</i>TEXT</a>
  </li>
  <li><a onclick="load('file-name')"><i class="material- 
    icons">copyright</i>Copyright</a>
  </li>
  <li class="button-dropdown">
    <a onclick="load('file-name') class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="material- 
     icons">assignment</i>Unit A<i class="fa fa-angle-right changed"></i> 
     </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
      <li>
        <a onclick="load('file-name')">Menu 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
      <li>
        <a onclick="load('file-name')">Menu 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and here is my js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {
      $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
      $(this).parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown- 
      menu").toggle().parents(".button-dropdown").children(".dropdown- 
      toggle").addClass("active")
      });
    $('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function () {
    $(this)
      .find('.changed')
      .toggleClass('fa-angle-down')
      .toggleClass('fa-angle-right');
     });
});
```

Here are the styles applied for drop-down-menu:

```
.dropdown-menu li > a {
  text-align: center;
 }

.dropdown-menu li:hover > a {
  background-color: #385170 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
 }

.changed {
 margin-left: 5px;
}
```

I need to add another child under Menu 1 and Menu 2.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What does your new element must have?

Comment: Hi k3lly.dev. I just need to add another dropdown menu under Menu1 and Menu2

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I found in your code is that you are defining the same event twice, which means that only the last one will be executed.

To append items with jQuery inside an event listener is as easy as:

#### Keeping code clean.

Globals at the beginning of your code:

```
var buttonDropdown = $(".button-dropdown");
```

And then your event listener for `dropdown-toggle` click:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function () {
   buttonDropdown.append("<li>new item</li>");
});
```

This will append a new item to `button-dropdown` everytime you click `dropdown-toggle`.

Here is an example:

```js
var buttonDropdown = $(".button-dropdown");

jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {
   $('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function (event) {
   let itemNumber = buttonDropdown.children().length;
   buttonDropdown.append("<ul><li>Menu "+itemNumber+"</li></ul>");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidenav sidenav-fixed" id="nav-mobile">
 <li>
  <a onclick="load('file-name')">
   <i class="material- icons">home</i>TEXT 
  </a>
 </li>
 <div class="divider"></div>
 <li>
  <a onclick="load('file-name')">
   <i class="material- icons">apps</i>TEXT
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a onclick="load('file-name')">
   <i class="material- icons">copyright</i>Copyright
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class="button-dropdown">
  <a onclick="load('file-name')" class="dropdown-toggle">
   <i class="material- icons">assignment</i>Unit A
   <i class="fa fa-angle-right changed"></i>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: block;">
   <li>
    <a onclick="load('file-name')">Menu 1</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: block;">
   <li>
    <a onclick="load('file-name')">Menu 2</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

***Note:*** This example is made from the context you provided. If it still not solves your entire issue, feel free to edit your question and comment here so I can update mine with the requirements for your question.

*And also, you did not provide any styles for your code, that's why it looks so plain.*

Comment: i appreciate your time. i made these changes and unfortunately, it didn't solve the issue. Just to be clear, what i need to add submenu 1 and submenu2 under Menu 1 and Menu 2. So it will look like Unit A >> Menu 1 >> submenu1 and submenu2 and Unit A >> Menu 2 >> submenu1 and submenu2. i added styles to the code. Thanks again.